# AWS MSK (Kafka) issue

Tags: java, apache-kafka, aws-msk

For our Kafka Cluster with ARN arn:aws:kafka:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:cluster/smtip-kafka-cluster-sandbox-new/547e0c64-8cd1-495c-999c-dkhad723424k-9, we’ve observed that whenever the CPU utilization goes beyond 80% during the load test, the cluster gets stuck at 40%-60% after the completion of the load test and doesn’t come down to normal range (<10%) unless we restart our application services.

We’ve observed this pattern multiple times for the past 2 weeks and below are a few of the time ranges that might help you look at the logs:

- 8th Nov 12:30 UTC - 9th Nov 8:30 UTC
- 3rd Nov 11:15 UTC - 5th Nov 4:10 UTC

We also keep seeing the following errors once in a while:

- java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
- java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space: failed reallocation of
  scalar replaced objects
- [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=3, fetcherId=1]  Error in
  response for fetch request (type=FetchRequest, replicaId=1,
  maxWait=500, minBytes=1, maxBytes=10485760, fetchData={},
  isolationLevel=READ_UNCOMMITTED, toForget=,
  metadata=(sessionId=950708108, epoch=27607))
  (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
- ERROR [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=2, fetcherId=1] Error for
  partition __amazon_msk_canary-0 at offset 4
  (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)

Any idea why it is behaving like this?

Comment: I suggest reaching out to MSK support